# Comparing an element from a list and print if not same

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting

Suppsoe I have the following list that containing `Fruit Name , Quantity , Rating` :

```
L1 = [['Apple', 1, 5], ['Banana', 2, 4], ['Grapes', 1, 5], ['Strawberry' ,1 ,5],['Blueberries' , 1 , 4]]
```

I want to compare two consecutive ratings only i.e 3rd Column and if two ratings are found same, it should not print the second one.

What I did was this ...

```
for final in L1:
    i = 0
    if final[i+1][2] < final[i][2]:
        print(final)
```

Output should be like :
`[['Apple', 1, 5] , ['Banana', 2, 4] , ['Grapes', 1, 5] , ['Blueberries' , 1 , 4]]`

Thanks in advance for help !

Comment: Can you provide a sample output as well ? From the question it isn't very clear on what you want.

Comment: @Harsh Parekh Check out my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `for` loop:

```
L1 = [['Apple', 1, 5], ['Banana', 2, 4], ['Grapes', 1, 5], ['Strawberry' ,1 ,5],['Blueberries' , 1 , 4]]

existing = []

for lst in L1:
    if len(existing) > 0:
        if lst[-1] != existing[-1]:
            print(lst)
    else:
        print(lst)

    existing.append(lst[-1])
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 1, 5]
['Banana', 2, 4]
['Grapes', 1, 5]
['Blueberries', 1, 4]
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your help ! much appreciated !